# Open or closed mapping between closed disk and unit sphere

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

I have a mapping between closed disk  $\overline B^{2}$ and unit sphere $S^2$. Notice $(0,0)\mapsto(0,0,-1)$.

$(x,y)\mapsto (\dfrac{x\sin(\pi\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}})}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}},\dfrac{y\sin(\pi\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}})}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}},-\cos(\pi\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}})$

I would love to prove this as open or closed mapping, but first I need to show that it's continuous surjection. I have already done the continuity part, but surjection is harder.

I need a hint to right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r=(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$ and think of the circle $r = c$ in the closed unit disc. The image of this circle under your map is

$$\{\sin (\pi c)(\cos t,\sin t,0)+(0,0,-\cos (\pi c)): t\in [0,2\pi]\}.$$

That is exactly the circle you get by intersecting $S_2$ with the plane $z= -\cos (\pi c).$

Answer (score 0):

(Part). The disk and the sphere are compact Hausdorff spaces so if A is a closed subset of the disc, then A is compact, so its continuous image on the sphere is compact, so the  image of A is closed. So it is a closed mapping.